# PHP error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo

I moved our database from MySQL to SQLite.

I now get an error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\calendar\insert.php on line 9

Here is the script:

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO events (fn, sn, bn, sd, ed) VALUES (:fn, :sn, :bn, STR_TO_DATE(:dp1,'%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(:dp2,'%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY))");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindParam("$key", $_POST[$key]);
}

$stmt->execute();

header("Location: /");
?>
```

I guess it is something relating to SQLite since I didn't get this error message on MySQL.

Can someone help?

Comment: That's not the problem. It worked fine on MySQL for 8 years.

Answer (score 1):

`STR_TO_DATE(:dp1,'%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(:dp2,'%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

`SQLLite` does not provide the date functions you have used in your query, hence your `prepare` call fails which causes the error on the next line.

Comment: Have to go through this http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and write some custom calculations